# meteor unexpected end of file error

Tags: curl, meteor

I am new to meteor, I am trying to install it on Ubuntu 14.04lts and I keep getting this error:

```
princek@princek-HP-ProBook-6540b:~$ curl https://install.meteor.com | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6121    0  6121    0     0    808      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--  1630
Downloading Meteor distribution
################################################################          90.1%
curl: (18) transfer closed with 8307587 bytes remaining to read

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Installation failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a temporary error that occurs when the package that was downloaded was interrupted due to a poor internet connection.

Simply try again, or try again later if your ISP has cached the file.

Comment: Does cached file by ISP make it hard to download?